# custom Keyboard popup not working properly for top most raw of keyboard in lollipop 5.1 Moto G device

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-softkeyboard

I set `KeyboardPreviewOffset="5dp"` and it is working fine on all devices and all versions of Android except Moto G with Lollipop 5.1.

For this particular version and device the top most raw of keyboard's `keyPreview` showing on the key but I want `keyPreview` above the key.

Except first raw I get every raw's `keyPreview` perfectly above the key, I have just faced the problem in first raw in Lollipop 5.1 version.

As shown in screen sort key <kbd>H</kbd> preview properly in second raw but key <kbd>E</kbd> preview not working as I need.

[image: this is not working as i want]

[image: this is working fine as i want]

Answer (score 0):

Finally i got answer,

this issue comes in all 5.1 and above device.

when i use onCreateCandidatesView() it solve my problem, you can also set visibility gone of your Candidateview.